# Zend_Date language translation

Tags: php, zend-framework, translation, zend-date

I have a function that returns me a date string using `Zend_Date`.

```
$date = new Zend_Date();
$date->setOptions(array('format_type' => 'php'));
$date->setTimestamp($timestamp);
return $date->toString($format);
```

When I set `$format` to `'l, d  F Y'` I expect something like:

`Środa, 13 stycznia 2010` (correct polish string what means `Wedneseday, 13 january 2010`) and it works good.

But when I open this page in a browser with locale set to english it returns me date string in english instead of polish that I want to see.

What and where should I set to get always polish date regardless of browser settings ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Pass the 3rd parameter to `toString()`:

```
$a = Zend_Date::now();
$a->setOptions(array('format_type' => 'php'));
$a->toString('l, d F Y', null, 'pl'); // wtorek, 12 stycznia 2010
```

Comment: or set that in Zend_Locale which is where Zend_Date takes the locale from.